# Another inequality with definite integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

Let be $ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous, monotone function. Then, if $a>0$ i must prove that the following inequality holds:
 $$\int_{-a}^{a}xf(f(x)) \geq0$$

I wonder if there is a simple proof for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have 
\begin{align}
\int_{-a}^axf(f(x))dx&=\int_0^axf(f(x))dx+\int_{-a}^0xf(f(x))dx\\
&=\int_0^axf(f(x))dx+\int_{a}^0(-s)f(f(-s))(-ds)\\
&=\int_0^as\left(f(f(s))-f(f(-s))\right)ds
\end{align}
and we deal with two cases:

- $f$ is non-decreasing. Since $-s\leq 0\leq s$, we have $f(-s)\leq f(s)$ and $f(f(-s))\leq f(f(s))$.
- $f$ is non-increasing. We have $f(-s) \geq f(s)$ and $f(f(-s))\leq f(f(s))$.

(in fact $f\circ f$ is non-decreasing in any case)

We can see we have equality if and only if $f\circ f$ is even.

Comment: nice solution. Thanks.

Comment: is it correct $f(f(-s))\leq f(s)$ ? I suppose you meant $f(f(-s))\leq f(f(s))$

Comment: @Chris : i think thats typo, should have been $ff(s)$

Comment: Right, fixed now.

Comment: @Davide Giraudo: in the last row we have that $f\circ f$ must be odd or even for getting equality?

Comment: In fact even, by bad. Thanks!